# How to change textbox value automatically based on variable combobox value?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I am using Visual Studio 2012

I want to know how to change textbox value automatically based on variable combobox value without pushing any button.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle its `SelectedIndexChanged` event

eg:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        TextBox1.Text = CStr(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have multiple conditions, use `Select Case`

```
Private Sub fy_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles fy.SelectedIndexChanged
    If fy.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Dim comboValue = CInt(fy.SelectedItem)
        Select Case comboValue
            Case 2400
                µmax.Text = 8.56 / 100000 * fcu.Text
            Case 2800
                µmax.Text = 7 / 100000 * fcu.Text
            Case Else
                'etc 'etc
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried this, but it didn't work,                                        Private Sub fy_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles fy.SelectedIndexChanged


        If fy.SelectedIndex = 2400 Then
            µmax.Text = CStr(8.56 / 100000 * fcu.Text)

        
        ElseIf fy.SelectedIndex = 3600 Then
            µmax.Text = CStr(7 / 100000 * fcu.Text)



        End If

    End Sub

Comment: what does it mean "didn't work" ??? try to be clear when asking for help or don't ask

Comment: the second method is working, thanks alot, you are a great tutor

Comment: sorry, but this error occurred when i tried to change the values in the previous second solution, (Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.)

Comment: It's pretty clear, you can't convert an empty string to a 'Double' number. Add an IF statement to check that your string is not empty before doing that.

Comment: you are right, but its not because empty string. i tried to add other case (case 3600) and the default text in the combobox is 3600, so it gives this error when running it, i tried other values it worked, so there is no other way to get over this by keeping the default combobox text = 3600,

Comment: @user3151946 maybe the "empty string" causing the error is fcu.Text. Use the debug to inspect your code. set breakpoints and study the variables

Comment: no the fcu.text has permanent default text = 250, the problem only happens if i add one of my cases number as combobox default text

Comment: Maybe because in that case you're not changing combobox value, therefore the event is not triggered? It's difficult to say without seeing the project

Comment: yeah that's true ( i thought that too), so can we add the same condition to other event, also i don't mind show any part of the project. (really thanks for your continuous support)

Answer (score 0):

try something like 
textbox.text = combobox.text

put this in the main page thing

Comment: it's not equal condition, i need to make condition like this: If fy.Text = 2400 Then
            µmax.Text = 8.56 / 100000 * fcu.Text

        ElseIf fy.Text = 2800 Then
            µmax.Text = 7 / 100000 * fcu.Text

        ElseIf fy.Text = 3600 Then
            µmax.Text = 5 / 100000 * fcu.Text

        ElseIf fy.Text = 4000 Then
            µmax.Text = 4.31 / 100000 * fcu.Text

        End If --- ( fy is the combo box ) ( µmax is the text box)